# span not vertically aligning text in the middle

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

All,
I have the following code:

```
<span style="width:450px; height:207px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; padding:0 0 0 10px; text-align:left;">
<b>Recipe Added By:</b> Test Person<br>
<b>Prep Time:</b> aljsdf<br>
<b>Cook Time:</b> asldfjdsf<br>
<b>Recipe Yield:</b> asflja<br>
<b>Recipe Category:</b> Main Dish   
</span>
```

This displays the text but the text is always aligned at the top. Any idea on how to center the text in the middle of the span?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a DIV and `display:table-cell`

```
<div style="width:450px; height:207px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; padding:0 0 0 10px; text-align:left;border:1px solid #ff0000">
<b>Recipe Added By:</b> Test Person<br>
<b>Prep Time:</b> aljsdf<br>
<b>Cook Time:</b> asldfjdsf<br>
<b>Recipe Yield:</b> asflja<br>
<b>Recipe Category:</b> Main Dish   
</div>
```

Answer (score 20):

Use in the span style `line-height:207px` to align vertically.

Comment: Yup, this but I think he meant `span` and not `div`. And also get rid of the `<b>` and `<br>` tags and replace them with `<strong>` and margin/padding respectively.

Answer (score 3):

```
<style>
span {
    width: 450px;
    height: 207px;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
<span>
<b>Recipe Added By:</b> Test Person<br>
<b>Prep Time:</b> aljsdf<br>
<b>Cook Time:</b> asldfjdsf<br>
<b>Recipe Yield:</b> asflja<br>
<b>Recipe Category:</b> Main Dish
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get it. I added a border to make it more visible.

```
<span style="width:450px; height:207px;  display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; padding:0 0 0 10px; text-align:left; border: solid 1px #000; ">
<b>Recipe Added By:</b> Test Person<br>
<b>Prep Time:</b> aljsdf<br>
<b>Cook Time:</b> asldfjdsf<br>
<b>Recipe Yield:</b> asflja<br>
<b>Recipe Category:</b> Main Dish   
</span>
```